# (Java) File still readable after lock

Tags: java, file, locking

I am currently trying to lock a file in Java to prevent other Methods from using it.

```
File someFile = new File(somePath);

FileLock lock = null;
FileChannel fromFileChannel = null;
FileOutputStream fromFileStream = null;
try {
    someFile.createNewFile();
    writeStringToFile(randomString, someFile);

    fromFileStream = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
    fromFileChannel = fromFileStream.getChannel();

    lock = fromFileChannel.lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, false);
} catch (IOException e) {
    fail();
}

System.out.println(someFile.canRead());
System.out.println(someFile.canWrite());
```

But why does canRead and canWrite both return true? Does the lock only count for the FileChannel?

Thank you very much

Comment: Reading the documentation, I think the `lock()` call throws an exception if the lock cannot be acquired.  Thus your locks are always `canRead` and `canWrite` if you get them.

Comment: @markspace It doesnt in that case (it never enters the catch block and lock() only throws IOExceptions), so the lock is acquired.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a research:

1. *This behaviour is incorrect for Windows, because File.canWrite() only checks the MS-DOS read-only flag, not the ACLs for the file. Therefore it will give false positives for files which you don't have access to write to*
2. `File file = new File("file.txt");`
   `boolean fileIsNotLocked = file.renameTo(file);` This is a simple way to check if file is locked on Windows.
3. Your lock works until you `fromFileChannel.close()` or `lock.release();`
4. I experimented with running 2 threads. The first one opens fileChannel and put a lock on it and writes. In second thread if you try to lock again the file you will get `OverlappingFileLockException` or if you try to write to file you will get `IOException` that another process blocked access. If you realease lock form thread 1 you are free to edit file in different threads.

So it looks very tricky and it all has to be super designed for locks if you wish to use them.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FileLock lock = null; FileChannel fromFileChannel = null; FileOutputStream fromFileStream = null;
                    fromFileStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToCreatePath.toFile());
                    fromFileChannel = fromFileStream.getChannel();

                    lock = fromFileChannel.lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, false);
                    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap("Hello from thread 1".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    fromFileChannel.write(buff);
                    //fromFileChannel.close();  - Close channel or release lock
                    // lock.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        thread1.start();

Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    FileChannel fromFileChannel = null; FileOutputStream fromFileStream = null; FileLock lock = null;
                    fromFileStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToCreatePath.toFile());
                    fromFileChannel = fromFileStream.getChannel();
                  //  lock = fromFileChannel.tryLock(); - FileLockException
                    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap("Hello from thread 2 :(".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    fromFileChannel.write(buff); // IOException
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread2.start();
```

Comment: The Problem is, they can. I tried to use canRead and canWrite as way of showing that function call.